# Getting no result in sqlite query

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am running following query on **sqlite** database. I know there is at least entry in `contact` table though i am getting no result.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM contact,
       phone,
       email 
 WHERE cnt_cnt_id = phn_cnt_id 
       AND phn_cnt_id = eml_cnt_id 
       AND cnt_cnt_id = 1111
```

form my query one can get idea that i'm trying to join those three tables. 
What should i do to retrive data having id say `1111` from all three  tables ?

**EDIT (table schemas) :**

```
 private static final String CONTACT_TABLE = "create table "
  + TABLE_NAME_CONTACT + "(" 
  + COLUMN_ID                   + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
  + COLUMN_CNT_CONTACT_ID           + " text not null, " 
  + COLUMN_CNT_FIRST_NAME           + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_CNT_LAST_NAME            + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_CNT_NICK_NAME            + " text not null"     
  + ");";

  private static final String PHONE_TABLE = "create table "
      + TABLE_NAME_PHONE + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID                   + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_PHN_CONTACT_ID           + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_PHN_NUMBER           + " text not null"
      + ");";

  private static final String EMAIL_TABLE = "create table "
      + TABLE_NAME_EMAIL + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID                   + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_EML_CONTACT_ID           + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_EML_EMAIL_ID             + " text not null"
      + ");";
```

Comment: Added the schema of tables.

Comment: What are the values present in these 3 tables?

Comment: @Mathew : user details as it name suggests.

Comment: @l-droid Do you have rows in your table which satisfy these 2 conditions: cnt_cnt_id = phn_cnt_id 
       AND phn_cnt_id = eml_cnt_id

Comment: You should use left join.. And why are your `Column_eml_contact_ID` text fields?

Comment: @I-droid dude you need to work on your RDBMS basics and learn more about how to create table relations.

Comment: There is entry in Contacts_TABLE, but is their any entry in PHONE_TABLE or EMAIL_TABLE

Comment: @Pankaj: yes, there is entry in any of those (PHONE_TABLE or EMAIL_TABLE) table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way :

```
 SELECT * FROM  
 contact  LEFT JOIN phone  ON cnt_cnt_id = phn_cnt_id                               
          LEFT JOIN  email ON phn_cnt_id = eml_cnt_id                                   
          WHERE cnt_cnt_id = 1111
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you haven't use Foreign Key which is mandatory to join two tables and retrieve data. [Look here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)  > How Foreign Key works.

You have to add `CONTACT_ID` as

```
Syntax :FOREIGN KEY(Child tbl id name ) REFERENCES TABLE_NAME_CONTACT(Parent tbl id name)

FOREIGN KEY(COLUMN_PHN_CONTACT_ID ) REFERENCES TABLE_NAME_CONTACT(COLUMN_CNT_CONTACT_ID)
FOREIGN KEY(COLUMN_EML_CONTACT_ID ) REFERENCES TABLE_NAME_CONTACT(COLUMN_CNT_CONTACT_ID)
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "CONTACT" (
    "cnt_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "fname" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "lname" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "nickname" TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "PHONE" (
    "ph_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "ph_number" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "cnt_id" FOREIGN KEY(cnt_id ) REFERENCES TABLE_NAME_CONTACT(cnt_id)
) 

CREATE TABLE "EMAIL" (
    "email_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "email_address" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "cnt_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(cnt_id ) REFERENCES TABLE_NAME_CONTACT(cnt_id)
)
```

Adjust your table name & fields and for more reference check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)

Hope this will help you.